# Android Working With Spinner And MultiAutoCompleteTextView Auto Populate List Items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

1. I'm new To Android Trying A Small App.
2. I Have A Spinner With List Of Items And I Have  MultiAutoCompleteTextView.
3. When I Select Any One Item From Spinner Then It Should Display Related To That Item. For Example If I Select Brand It Should Allow Items In MultiAutoCompleteTextView Related To Brand(Adidas,Lee,Puma)Like That.
4. If I Choose Color (Blue,Black,Yellow,Green)Like That.
5. Here Is My Activity......

---

```
  package com.example.ns2.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] color={"Blue","Black","Red","Yellow","Green","Pink","Sony","LG","Samsung"};

    MultiAutoCompleteTextView text1;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text1= (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, color);
        text1.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        text1.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.SearchKey, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }






   /* @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

    /*@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
        });
    }
}
```

---

1. This is My Layout......

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.ns2.testing.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/like"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/like"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp">
    </Spinner>
    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Value.... "
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

1. Can Anyone Help Me To Solve This...
2. Thankful To Them.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener

I have created Category and Subcategory spinners. Subcategory values are showed based on Category selection. Following is the code sample:

```
    spn_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        String selection = spn_category.getSelectedItem().toString();

                     // Based on this selection category, you can select which subcategory to show

                    ArrayAdapter<String> selection_subcat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ServiceProviderProfileEdit.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CategoryInfo.getSubCategories(selection));
                    spn_subcategory.setAdapter(selection_subcat);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        // your code here (optional)
                    }

                });
```

Hope it will help you..!

Comment: Thanks Boss@Dhaval